# Receiving this Error "in if (is.na(s)) { : the condition has length > 1 " on R when using Stargazer for 6 multiple regressions

Tags: r, linear-regression, panel-data, stargazer, olsmultiplelinearregression

I am currently doing some panel data regressions in R and I am trying to put  multiple models side-by-side using stargazer

When I put 5 panel data models using stargazer  I receive an output

```r
reglogglobal2 <- plm(log1p(GDP_growth) ~ log1p(CO2emissions_per_capita) + log1p(inflation) + log1p(forest_area_sq_km) + log1p(nitrous_oxide_emissions) + log1p(methane_emissions), data = pdataglobal, model = "within")
stargazer(reglogglobal2, reglogglobal, reglog32, reglog33, reglog31,reg1og56,
          type = "text",
          header = FALSE,
          no.space = TRUE)
```

but when I put 6  I receive this error

[image]

```
Error in if (is.na(s)) { : the condition has length > 1
```

All my models and dataframes are defined . What does this error mean ?  How can I solve it please  ?
Thank you

I was able to produce  stargazer  output  with 6 lm models  so I can confirm that stargazer works with 6 linear regressions.
Not sure if it is because I am using panel data .

Comment: In which line does it error? The call to `plm` or the call to `stargazer`? If the former, there's no need to include `stargazer` in the code or the tags.

Comment: I suspect `plm`. I couldn't immediately find a reference to `is.na(a)` in the `plm` function itself, so it's likely buried deeper in the package. I suggest you go through the various functions in the [package source](https://github.com/ycroissant/plm/tree/main/R) and/or raise a [new issue](https://github.com/ycroissant/plm/issues/new) with a reproducible example (including sample data). Unless somebody has run into that before, there's likely not a lot more we can do without a reproducible example (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Comment: You don't really give us enough info to answer your question, since we don't have the data to reproduce it.  What I'd suggest is pretty generic:  make sure all your packages are up to date (run `update.packages(ask = FALSE)` to do this), then if you still get the error, run `traceback()` after it, and if that doesn't tell you how to fix it, edit your question to include the `traceback()` results.

Comment: Obligatory mention that ‘stargazer’ is an all round terrible package. I strongly recommend not using it. There are lots of better alternatives, such as ‘modelsummary’ or “texreg’.

Comment: @r2evans   . It is a stargazer  issue. Thanks

Comment: Turns out the issue was  the long object names . I shortened it and  the  stargazer  function  now is working is displaying all 6 regressions without any error message. Thank  you everyone for their help

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if that's still helpful for someone, but I had a similar problem and I found a quick solution here on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/ucmtdn/issue_with_stargazer_package_after_update_to_r_420/?rdt=36823

Apparently it's just a question of reducing the length of the model names. In any case it worked for me when I changed to shorter model names.